# Using a color reference card to verify monitor calibration

Tags: display, color-profiles, calibration

I use a HueyPRO for monitor calibration and use it on my Macs. After calibrating my monitor, I roll through all the other profiles available. Some profiles produce VERY different colors and I'm thinking to myself, "Which profile is showing me the correct colors?"

I was thinking about using some kind of reference card (like the X-Rite ColorChecker Chart) to verify which profile is the correct one. However, no reviews or tutorials mention using color reference cards for monitor calibration verification.

To me, it would make sense to hold the color reference card up to my monitor and compare them to see if the colors match up.

Is my thinking correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perception of colors will vary some from projected light (the LCD) than reflected light (a printed card).  They will have different brightnesses, and the LCD emits powerful enough to compensate for your "house" lights.

I definitely think an electronic tool will be far more accurate than the human eye.

Comment: +1: The human eye is one of the poorest tools for color calibration. . .

Answer (score 0):

The way I would use a color calibration chip card is to use the card to calibrate an imaging device, like a camera or scanner.  Once the imager is calibrated correctly, you can capture an image of the card itself and compare the profile generated by the measurement device with the image of the card.

Comment: Simpler to just generate the RGB color of the card on the display.

Comment: @stark That matches what the card is *supposed* to look like, and not what the card *actually* looks like.